# MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL is blocking subsequent ACTION_UP on my button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a button on one of my fragments, that sits inside a relative layout. 
It's a rather large button, and when I fat finger it I get a ACTION_CANCEL motion event rather than ACTION_DOWN (it works perfectly fine with finger tips). This prevents it from registering the subsequent ACTION_UP (I assume the view's parent is taking over). I tried using the requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent() method on the parent, to no avail.

Here is my onTouch implementation:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    //debugging
    Log.v("TOUCH EVENT", event.toString());


    int action = event.getAction(); 





    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        mButton.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        //Do stuff...

        return true;

    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

        //Do other stuff...

        return true;

    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL){

        return false;
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Your thumb is too fat.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    return false;
}
```

Note that the button also uses custom background resources. I start an AsyncTask when the button is pressed and the background changes based on the progress of that task. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with the problem or not.

EDIT: I walked all the way up the View hierarchy to ViewRootImpl, and still no luck in calling requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent() on it. Weird thing is this shows in the log when my button sticks:

08-26 11:06:15.287: D/ViewRootImpl(5428): [ViewRootImpl] action cancel - 1, s:31 s(atmel):-1.0 eccen:1.3333334

So obviously it seems that the action is either being cancelled before it even gets inside the ViewRootImpl or right after. How is this even possible?

Update: Still no progress on this... anyone?

Update 2: I think this may be a device dependent issue. I'm using a Galaxy S4

Comment: I am currently seeing this, or something very similar, on a Samsung S7. My buttons are not all big I am not using AsyncTask. If you put in a decent pause, it works. If this was a keyboard, I would think this was something to prevent key bounce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a device dependent issue with the Galaxy S4, I was unable to reproduce it on other devices. I ended up just cancelling the task if a `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` was picked up.

Comment: I have stumbled upon this problem too and hope to have a look at it in the next couple of days. I will start here: [http://codetheory.in/understanding-android-input-touch-events/](http://codetheory.in/understanding-android-input-touch-events/) This kind of "cancellation" happens only if I lay a large part of my hand on the display, like placing the hand for writing. I have a Samsung Tab Active 365, Android 4.4.

Comment: Same issue with Tab S8 Ultra. If a large portion of the screen is touched the activity gets spammed with ACTION_CANCEL.